# Directly passing the multi line output of grep to a function?

Tags: unix, scripting

My code looks like this:

```
ls -l path/folderName | grep "^A"
```

This would give me multiple lines of output.

> Is it possible to directly pass the output from grep to a function?

I would like to pass the output of `grep` to a function one value at a time.

I have got suggestions to store the output of grep in a temporary file and then use a loop to pass the values to the function one at a time.

I would like to know if there is a shortcut.

Comment: What do you need exactly? Please give an example of input and the desired output

Comment: I would like to do something like this: ls -l path/folderName | grep "^A" | functionName

Comment: Have you tried the simple `ls -l path/folderName | grep "^A" | xargs -I {} functionName {} ` ?

Comment: I just tried it, is there by any chance an error with the syntax? I'm getting an error that says: "xargs: functionName: No such file or directory"

Comment: It depends on your shell. You can convert `functionName` into a separate shell script to ensure it works always.